# Prime Factors of the Composit Terms of Arithmetic Progressions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Dirichlet's theorem states that for any two positive coprime integers a and d, there are infinitely many primes or the form a + nd, where n is a non-negative integer. My question is concerning the composit terms of such arithmetic progressions, and particularly, concerning the prime factors thereof. Here are some examples and what I have found so far:

If the initial term is 1 and the common difference is 2, every prime other than 2 will appear as a factor of a composite term. I know that once a prime appears as a factor of a term, then the prime will continue to be a factor forevermore. My question is specifically concerning the initial appearance of the prime.

In any arithmetic progression of the form a + nd where a and d are any two positive coprime integers, and n is a non-negative integer, will every prime other than those which are factors of the common difference appear as a factor of a composite term?

If the initial term is 1 or 3 and the common difference is 2, I have found the answer to be yes. Likewise, if the initial term is 5 or 7, and the common difference is 6, the answer is yes. These I have checked by hand and have found proofs for.

Here is one specific example of what I am asking about:

If I set up the arithmetic progression with 2309 as the first term and use 2310 as the common difference, will I find a multiple of 13 within the first 13 terms? I know that the answer to this is yes. My question is, what is the proof for all such arithmetic progressions and the prime factors of the composit terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phenomenon you observed with $a=2309$, $d=2310$, and $p=13$ is not at all an accident. It occurs quite generally.

Suppose that the prime $p$ does not divide $d$. Then for $n=0,1,\dots,p-1$ the numbers $a+nd$ are pairwise incongruent modulo $p$. Thus their remainders on division by $p$ travel, in some order, through the numbers $0,1,\dots,p-1$. In particular there is an $n$, with $0\le n\le p-1$, such that $a+nd$ is divisible by $p$.

*Remarks:* $1$. The same proof works if instead of a prime $p$, we use a positive integer $m$ which is relatively prime to $d$.

$2.$ To show that if $0\le i\lt j\le p-1$, the numbers $a+id$ and $a+jd$ are incongruent modulo $p$, suppose to the contrary that $p$ divides their difference. Then $p$ divides $(j-i)d$. But since $p$ and $d$ are relatively prime, it follows that $p$ divides $j-i$. This is impossible, since $0\lt j-i\lt p$.